# can't open system settings(Ubuntu 17.10), icon is visible but settings don't display

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, system-settings

I installed Ubuntu 17.10.1 today on my laptop, and i Opened settings and moved the dock to the bottom, and the settings window just disappeared. The answer given in the following link don't help me to disable the second virtual monitor from the command line, and restored the settings window back to my normal laptop screen view:

[disable second virtual monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366813/disable-second-non-existent-screen-from-command-line)

so what i do?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a little workaround did restore the System Settings for me (assuming one had this problem after changing the dock position just like me):

**First** in terminal : sudo apt install dconf-editor

**Second** open dconf-editor and Navigate to org > gnome > shell-extensions> dash-to-dock > dock-position

**Finally** Restore dock position to it's default value (or left)

System Settings is working properly now.