# How can I get my Raspberry pi to run Dual monitor running ubuntu

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors

I have a Raspberry 4 / 4G running Ubuntu, it has a 7” touch Screen connected with a ribbon cable. When Plug a TV or other Monitor into the HDMI port I only get sound. As soon get no options in the settings for the second monitor.

This what I get when I run xrandr with the second monitor plunged in

```
ubuntu@brad-pi:~$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 800 x 480, current 800 x 480, maximum 800 x 480
default connected primary 800x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   800x480        0.00*
```

any help or point in the right direction  would appreciated

Comment: There are 2 micro hdmi ports on the Raspi 4. Hook each one up to a moniter

Answer (score 0):

I have the same configuration as you. (Ubuntu on a raspberry pi with 7" display with a second monitor connected via HDMI cable). The following worked for me.

```
sudo nano /boot/fireware/usercfg.txt
```

After the file is open

```
# Definitely required
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d

# If one of the monitors have dark border
disable_overscan=1

# Not sure what it does. Might not be required.
max_framebuffers=2
```

Save and exit. Install the following

```
sudo apt install xfce4-settings
```

Reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

After login to check the displays

```
xfce4-display-settings &
```

For me, this was displaying two monitors side by side (one huge and another small). To get the name of the displays:

```
xrandr --current
```

If it is displaying two different monitors

```
xrandr --output <projector> --same-as <desktop>
```

where in my case  was HDMI-1 and  was DSI-1. To switch off the  (DSI-1) monitor

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 && xrandr --output DSI-1 --off
```

This will switch off the DSI-1 monitor.

My references: [Ref1](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=131&t=270539&p=1641022&hilit=dual%20monitor%20ubuntu#p1641022), [Ref2](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=244422), [Ref3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366813/disable-second-non-existent-screen-from-command-line)